# Almost surely equality

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

suppose that X = Y almost surely.i.e. P(X=Y)=1. Then how can one show that the events $X^{-1}(M)$and  $Y^{-1}(M)$ are equal almost
surely for each Borel set M ∈ B.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$(X^{-1}(M) \setminus Y^{-1}(M))\cup (Y^{-1}(M) \setminus X^{-1}(M))$$ $$= \{\omega \mid X(\omega)\in M, Y(\omega)\notin M\}\cup \{\omega \mid X(\omega)\notin M, Y(\omega)\in M\} $$ $$\subset \{\omega \mid X(\omega)\not= Y(\omega)\}  $$

Comment: @user133834 please let me know if I can help any further. If you are ok with it, please consider accepting the answer: it would look good for this site's (and mine) statistics.